# Show low resolution image before completely load big image

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am using directive

```
app.directive('hires', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { hires: '@' },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          initialLoad = false

          element.bind('load', function() {
            initialLoad = true;
            if(!scope.hires) return;
            element.attr('src', scope.hires);
          });

          attrs.$observe('hires', function(value) {
            if(!value) return;
            if(initialLoad) element.attr('ng-src', value);
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

it working fine when page load .But what i trying to when some one click on button then i add image link then it not working .My code

```
 <img hires="{{showpopup_img}}" ng-src="http://asasa.net/thumb/assas/{{deals.image}}" />
showpopup_img when some one click on button then it add image url not on page load.
    $scope.mapcall = function (deals) {
     $scope.showpopup_img='http://asasaas.net/big/publicdeals/'+deals.id+'.jpg';
}
```